# Jquery DOM element to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is it possible to convert DOM element into string?
Basically I need something like this:

List:

```
<div selector="HERE DOM ELEMENT" > Some element</div>
<div selector="HERE DOM ELEMENT 2" > Some element 2</div>
<div selector="HERE DOM ELEMENT 3" > Some element 3</div>
```

And when I click on some of selectors I would like it to highlight specify Dom Element.

This list is generated by script like this :[http://tinybug.smartbird.pl/example/index.html](http://tinybug.smartbird.pl/example/) . And when I click on Selector list, it sometimes selects the wrong Dom Element.

Any ideas?

Best Regards

Comment: @Matt, unable to understand what your question is. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: really not clear what you are wanting

Comment: Sorry. 
I want to convert DOM element into a string to use $('html').find( Dom element as string );

Comment: What's your *real* HTML, what do you want to click on and what output do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store DOM elements as string and find them later by that string. You have to somehow identify those elements whether by id, or class, or even tag name with all attributes, but you have to identify them. That will help you to use that string in jQuery.

I can suggest some kind of algorithm:

- find the ID of element if it has such and store it as a string `#id_of_element`
- otherwise find the class name of the element and store the element using tag name, class name and the index in the list of matched elements, because there could be several elements with the same tag name and the same class name
- think of any other identification method which can be specific to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

isn't the value of the property **selector** already a string? what about putting an specific **ID** on an element in it?

```
<div class="selectable" selector="element_1">Click to select element 1</div>
<div class="selectable" selector="element_2">Click to select element 2</div>
<div class="selectable" selector="element_3">Click to select element 3</div>        

<div id="element_1">ELEMENT 1</div>
<div id="element_2">ELEMENT 2</div>
<div id="element_3">ELEMENT 3</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("div.selectable").click(function(){
        var div_selector = $(this).attr("selector");                
        $('html').find("#"+div_selector).css("background-color", "#ddd");
    });
</script>
```